# invalid arguments from widget parameters?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I used two buttons which make same thing on subcategories screen. On of them in buttom of the screen, other one stays in subcategories part (Empty Card )of the screen, from the bottom button I can add new subcategory but when I pushed to the EmptyCard to add subcategory, adding screen is oppening but when I try to push add button, I took invalid argument(s) error, Can someone help me..

```
class CategoryModel{
  CategoryModel({this.categoryId,this.categoryImagePath,this.categoryName,this.categoryColor,this.subCategory});
  final int categoryId;
  final SubCategoryModel subCategory;
  final Color categoryColor;
  final String categoryImagePath;
  final String categoryName;
  final List<SubCategoryModel> subCategoryModels=[SubCategoryModel(subCategoryId: null)];

}
class SubCategoryModel{
  SubCategoryModel({this.subCategoryId,this.subCategoryImagePath,this.subCategoryName, this.categoryColor});
  final int subCategoryId;
  final Color categoryColor;
  final subCategoryImagePath;
  final subCategoryName;
```

```
class EmptyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  EmptyCard({this.where});
  final String where;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: (){
          if(where=="homeScreen"){
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Menü Ekle",route:where),
            );
          }
          else if(where=="subCategoryScreen"){
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Tarif Ekle",route:where),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          width: 180,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.1),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined,size: 100,color: Colors.grey.shade400,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: BorderedText(
            child:Text(
              categoryModels[widget.categoryId].categoryName,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0XFFFFFB00),
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontFamily: "Graduate"
              ),
            ),
            strokeWidth: 5,
            strokeColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          elevation: 5,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF2C3D4).withOpacity(1),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            iconSize: 40,
            color: Color(0xFFA2000B),
          ),
          actions: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 27,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/cuttedlogo.PNG"),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/logoBGopacity.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                    itemCount:categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      if(categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels[index].subCategoryId==null){
                        return EmptyCard(where: "subCategoryScreen");
                      }
                      return SubCategoryCard(subCategoryId:widget.categoryId,subcategoryName: categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels[index].subCategoryName,
                        subCategoryImagePath: categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels[index].subCategoryImagePath,
                        subCategoryColor: categoryModels[widget.categoryId].subCategoryModels[index].categoryColor,);
                    }
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid),
                        color: kColorTheme7,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                      ),
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(categoryId:widget.categoryId,buttonText: "Tarif Ekle", route:"subCategoryScreen"),
                          );
                        },
                        child: BorderedText(
                          strokeWidth: 5,
                          strokeColor: Colors.black,
                          child:Text("Tarif Ekle",style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily:'Graduate',
                            fontSize:30,
                          ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AddMenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  AddMenuScreen({this.categoryId,this.buttonText, this.route});
  final int categoryId;
  final String route;
  final String buttonText;
  static String id="addMenuScreen";
  @override
  _AddMenuScreenState createState() => _AddMenuScreenState();
}

class _AddMenuScreenState extends State<AddMenuScreen> {
  final stickerList= List<String>.generate(23, (index) => "images/sticker$index");
  int selectedIndex=-1;
  Color _containerForStickersInactiveColor=Colors.white;
  Color _containerForStickersActiveColor=Colors.black12;

  String chosenImagePath;
  String newCategoryName;
  int addScreenImageNum;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        color: kColorTheme9,
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(40),topLeft: Radius.circular(40)),
          ),
          child:Padding(
            padding:EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: kColorTheme2,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90)
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontFamily:"Graduate",
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      newCategoryName=value;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border:OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Menü ismi belirleyin",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                        fontFamily: "Graduate",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Text(" Yana kadırarak menünüz icin bir resim secin",textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Graduate", fontSize: 12),),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: stickerList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          color: index == selectedIndex ?
                          _containerForStickersActiveColor :
                          _containerForStickersInactiveColor,
                        ),
                        child:TextButton(
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage("images/sticker$index.png"),
                          ),
                          onPressed: (){
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex = index;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        );
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    color: kColorTheme7,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                  ),
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      if(widget.route=="homeScreen"){
                        Navigator.pop(context, ModalRoute.withName(HomeScreen.id));
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomeScreen(newCategoryName: newCategoryName,
                            newCategoryImagePath: "images/sticker$selectedIndex.png")));
                      }
                      else if(widget.route=="subCategoryScreen"){
                        Navigator.pop(context, ModalRoute.withName(SubCategoriesScreen.id));
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SubCategoriesScreen(categoryId: widget.categoryId,subCategoryName: newCategoryName,
                          subCategoryImagePath:"images/sticker$selectedIndex.png" )));
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(widget.buttonText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color:  Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: "Graduate", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```